# JasperReports Subreport Stretching

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport, stretching

I'm trying to create an xls-report with JasperReports.
For that I use JasperReports 5.5.0 (and iReport in the same version) and apache poi 3.9.

The base structure is a master-report with a subreport and this subreport also contains another subreport. For better understanding some code samples:

Masterreport:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ada06392-98fc-4512-99d3-a4008c86ed40">
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.create.custom.palette" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.evaluation.time.enabled" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="3.1384283767210035"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="34"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="subreportDisLayer" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" isForPrompting="false"/>
<field name="nextLayerList" class="java.util.List"/>
<field name="field1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="field2" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="13" splitType="Stretch">
        <subreport isUsingCache="true" runToBottom="true">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="13" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="222f19ef-c9f7-40a9-ae44-11ef6e15f1ad"/>
            <subreportParameter name="subsubreportLayer">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{subsubreportLayer}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{nextLayerList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportLayer}]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="40" y="0" width="30" height="13" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="ab260763-72ff-47ff-ad53-dfedde447908"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement>
                <font size="8"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="2" tabStopWidth="4"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="70" y="0" width="50" height="13" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="c408ac05-ee11-4e49-9609-179429b76e20"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement>
                <font size="8"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="2" tabStopWidth="4"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Subreport 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="ada06392-98fc-4512-99d3-a4008c86ed40">
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.create.custom.palette" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.evaluation.time.enabled" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="3.1384283767210035"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="34"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="subsubreportLayer" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" isForPrompting="false"/>
<field name="nextLayerList" class="java.util.List"/>
<field name="field3" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<detail>
    <band height="13" splitType="Stretch">
        <subreport isUsingCache="true" >
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="13" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="222f19ef-c9f7-40a9-ae44-11ef6e15f1ad"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{nextLayerList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subsubreportLayer}]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="274" y="0" width="100" height="13" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="7fae7678-55c7-4308-9977-f71e215b38c9"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement>
                <font size="8"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="2" tabStopWidth="4"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field3}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

The second subreport looks almost the same like the first one.

My problem is, that if the row height of the master is larger than the whole band height of a subreport, the subreport won't stretch its band height to the masters row height.
I know it has to be just a simple combination of settings, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected it was a simple combination of the stretching-option...
The elements of the master-report mustn't stretch with overflow, but must have the property *net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text* set to *true*.
The first subreport follows the same rule, but the elements of the second subreport must stretch with overflow.